# can we get ID of the Autogenerateeditbutton="true" in detailsview control in .cs file

Tags: asp.net

i have an requirment where i need  to  get  the can we get   ID of the Autogenerateeditbutton="true" of  detailsview  control in .cs  file

is there any way we  can do it 
  thank you

Comment: on which event do you need it? and which id? the clientID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can without first converting the field to a templatefield.

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Visible='true'
                             CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>

                     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```